# Regex: Find those particular html tags that contain these words (strings)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this tags:

`<span class="text_obisnuit2">* Not&#259;:</span>John Wells - <em>My Dreams</em>, Albatros Books, 1986.</p>`

and this one:

`<span class="text_obisnuit1">* Not&#259;:</span>Mariah Carey - <em>Lovers on the road</em>, BackStreet Books, 1965.</p>`

So, I want to find those particular html tags **`<span class="text_obisnuit2">`** that contain these words (strings):  **`Albatros`** and  **`<em>`** and **`</em>`**  (The first line)

Comment: Obligatory [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5477531)

Comment: At first I thought you wanted to do this in production, but then I noticed the notepad++ tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a straightforward one, but it requires the 'Albatros' to come after the `<em>` tag ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sx7Iao/1)):

```
(<span class="text_obisnuit2">).*<em>.*<\/em>.*Albatros.*
```

The following one doesn't care in which order they are ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sx7Iao/2/)):

```
(<span class="text_obisnuit2">).*(<em>.*<\/em>.*Albatros.*|Albatros.*<em>.*<\/em>.*)
```

Here is another variation, where the digit(s) after `text_obisnuit` don't matter and the entire `span` tag is captured as the first group ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sx7Iao/3/)):

```
(<span class="text_obisnuit\d+">.*<\/span>).*(<em>.*<\/em>.*Albatros.*|Albatros.*<em>.*<\/em>.*)
```

All regexes assume the entries are each on their own line in the file. Perhaps it makes more sense to detect for `<p>` and `</p>` as the boundaries, but for that we would need to have a larger excerpt from your input file.

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<span class="text_obisnuit2">(?=.*?<em>.*?</em>)(?=.*?\bAlbatros\b).*$`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<span class="text_obisnuit2">   # literally
(?=                             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
.*?                           # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
<em>                          # literally open em tag
.*?                           # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
</em>                         # literally close em tag
)                               # end lookahead
(?=                             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
.*?                           # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\bAlbatros\b                  # Albatros with word boundaries
)                               # end lookahead
.*                              # 0 or more any character but newline
$                               # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: thanks Toto. Also, can you make the same for `</em>`, so to  find those particular html tags that contain also `</em>` not just `<em>`

Comment: @JustMe: Change `(?=.*?<em>)` to `(?=.*?<em>.*?</em>)`, see my edit.